# Error 1 in OrderModify

Tags: mql4

I'm trying to modify an Order, but I always get **`Error #1`**.

From my research, I have discovered that error 1 means I have input parameter in a wrong way. How can I fix my **`OrderModify()`** function?

```
    stoploss = NormalizeDouble(Ask - Point * TrailingStop,Digits);
    int ticket;
    takeprofit = NormalizeDouble(Ask + Point * TrailingStopTP,Digits);
    double minstoplevel = MarketInfo( Symbol(), MODE_STOPLEVEL );
    if(stoploss > NormalizeDouble(Ask - Point*minstoplevel,Digits)) {
        stoploss = NormalizeDouble(Ask - Point*minstoplevel,Digits);
    }
    if(takeprofit < NormalizeDouble( Ask + Point*minstoplevel2, Digits )) {
        takeprofit = NormalizeDouble( Ask + Point*minstoplevel2, Digits );
    }
    if(AccountFreeMarginCheck(Symbol(),OP_SELL,lotsize)>0) {
        ticket=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,lotsize,Ask, 0, 0.0, 0.0, "comment", MagicNumber, 0, Lime);
        if(ticket<0) {
            Print("Order send failed with error #",GetLastError());       
        } else {
            Print("Order send sucesso!! Ticket#", ticket);
            res=OrderModify(ticket,OrderOpenPrice(),stoploss,takeprofit,0,Blue);
            if(res==false) {
                Print("Error modifying order!, error#",GetLastError());
            } else {
                Print("Order modified successfully, res#", res);
            }            
        }
    } else {
        Print("Sem dinheiro na conta D=");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Not exactly "*wrong*", `OrderModify()` legally sets `_LastError == 1`

There might be a bit surprise, but **`OrderModify()`** has an obligation to signal **`_LastError == 1`** in case, the call was both syntactically and semantically correct, however, the values supplied for modification(s) were actually the very same, as the identified **`ticket#`** has already had in database.

This means, there was nothing to modify, as all the attributes already had the "**quasi-*new***" target value(s).

One may pre-check all fields for a potential identity, which might allow our code to skip the `OrderModify()` call in this very case of an identity-of-{ current | target } values.

```
ERR_NO_RESULT == 1               // No error returned, but the result is unknown
```

`GetLastError()` - returns a last generated error-code. The same value is available via a system variable named **`_LastError`**. It's value can be reset before a critical activity to zero by calling **`ResetLastError()`**.

Error codes are defined in **`stderror.mqh`**.

To print the error description you can use the **`ErrorDescription()`** function, defined in **`stdlib.mqh`** file

```
#include <stderror.mqh>
#include <stdlib.mqh>
```

Comment: hm, I don't think this is the case. Because It's already checking it with minstoplevel

Comment: What do you try to state, Filipe? An error in common sense is reported by ( OrderModify() == False && _LastError != ERR_NO_RESULT ). Detail diagnostic + logging typically follow this situation, not an ERR_NO_RESULT singularity case. Is it clearer or did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that even though the entry price, stoploss, and take profit parameters to the **`OrderModify()`** call appear to be the same, they likely differ by a fraction of a unit ( smaller than "Digits" ).

To fix this,
simply normalize the parameters to make sure they are a maximum of **`Digits`** decimal places long.

```
double entryPrice = NormalizeDouble( entryPrice, Digits );
double stoploss   = NormalizeDouble( stoploss,   Digits );
double target     = NormalizeDouble( target,     Digits );
```

Then pass them into the `OrderModify()` call.

Comment: With all due respect, this is **not correct, sir.** The call to `NormalizeDouble()` is out of question not the reason for `_LastError == ERROR_NO_RESULT`. For details ref. to *(cit.:)* "There might be a bit surprise, but **`OrderModify()`** has an obligation to signal **`_LastError == 1`** in case, the call was both syntactically and semantically correct, however, the values supplied for modification(s) were actually the very same, as the identified **`ticket#`** has already had in database." You might already want to update your answer to better reflect the reality of the O/P posted problem.

Comment: has solve for me.